# Expanding a token selection operator

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3, lexer

I have an expressions in ANTLR3

```
num_addition
    : num_multi ((plus^|minus^) num_multi)*
    ;
```

I want to change the tokens 'plus' and 'minus' to a different token So i tried to made this rewrite rule.

```
num_addition
    : num_multi (plus num_multi)* -> ^(num_multi ^(plus_special num_multi)*)
    | num_multi (minus num_multi)* -> ^(num_multi ^(minus_special num_multi)*)
    ;
```

If I do this the generation in ANTLRWORKS seems to take longer but it generated the correct grammar and tokens. If I apply this style to other rules such as 'multi' and 'divide' and 'equalequal' etc. it eventually gets to the point where ANTLRWORKS wont do anything when I press Generate.

There are no errors according to ANTLRWORKS but when I pres generate nothing happens.

Am I incorrectly rewriting for what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't inject just any production or terminal into your AST which are not matched in the parser rule you're creating the AST for. In your case, you can insert `plus` or `minus` since they are matched by the parser rule, but you can't insert `plus_special` or `minus_special` since these are not matched by the parser rule `num_addition`.

You *can* inject imaginary tokens though.

Try something like this:

```
grammar T;

tokens {
  // Some imaginary tokens:
  PLUS_SPECIAL;
  MINUS_SPECIAL;
}

// ...

num_addition
 : (a=num_multi -> $a) ( PLUS  b=num_multi -> ^(PLUS_SPECIAL  $num_addition $b)
                       | MINUS b=num_multi -> ^(MINUS_SPECIAL $num_addition $b)
                       )*
 ;

// ...

PLUS : '+';
MINUS : '-';
```

Comment: I'd expect that you can also insert normal tokens (PLUS instead PLUS_SPECIAL). But you are right about arbitrary productions.

Comment: @MikeLischke, yes, you can insert normal tokens (or ASTs from productions) as long as they are matched inside the production: you cannot insert normal tokens which are not matched inside the production from which you want to create the AST. I'll rephrase my answer.

Comment: Great Answer. Exactly what I was looking for! The grammer generates but it definately seems slower to do so.

Comment: I used this code in all of my Math and Logic operators and its taking about 4 minutes to even begin the code generation using ANTLRWorks. It was only about 20 seconds prior. This seems unexpected.

Comment: @meriley do you have `backtrack=true;` defined, by any chance? If so, you could try enabling `memoize=true;` as well to speed things up. Giving ANTLR more heap-space is also worth trying. Also check its not ANTLRWorks that is messing things up: also test from your shell.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the issue. I wasnt being very efficient with one of my new rules and it was causing things to bloat.